# Sonatype 401 when trying to push Maven snapshots

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to push a SNAPSHOT atrifact to the Sonatype OSS repo, but Maven is throwing an error saying Sonatype responded with a 401. I am using Fedora 19 with Maven 3.0.5 and all updates have been applied through yum.

I have also worked through each step listed in http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/11/what-to-do-when-nexus-returns-401.

What else might cause a 401 from Sonatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with the version of Maven distributed with Fedora 19. Once I downloaded the Maven 3.1.1 distribution, deploying to Sonatype worked without a hitch.